# include tikz commands via Sexpr

Tags: r, latex, sweave, tikz

I want to use tikz to implement basic graphics in an automated report created by Sweave. Therefore, I created an R function, returning the tikz command, based on the data. My code looks similar to this:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
y <- 20
code <- cat(paste("\\draw (0pt, ",y,"pt) circle (5pt)", sep=""))
@
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Sexpr{code}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which does not work ... I get the string instead of the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\Sexpr`, just put the chunk in the `tikzpicture` environment, and add the chunk option `results=tex`.  For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
y <- 20
cat(paste0("\\draw (0pt, ",y,"pt) circle (5pt)", sep=""))
@
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This isn't tested, so you may need to tweak it a little.